# How to include directories when building Arduino software

Tags: makefile, arduino, include

I'm making a small Arduino project. The official Arduino IDE is really terrible, so I'm using Netbeans to develop instead. This is my makefile:

```
OBJDIR          = ../build

ARDUINO_DIR = /usr/share/arduino

TARGET      = main

MCU     = atmega328p

F_CPU       = 16000000

ARDUINO_PORT    = /dev/ttyACM0
AVRDUDE_ARD_PROGRAMMER  = arduino
AVRDUDE_ARD_BAUDRATE    = 115200

include /usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk
```

I want to use some headers located in `/usr/local/include/myproject`, so in the source code I add:

```
#include "myproject/someheader.h"
```

Now, when I try to compile the project, I get an error saying

```
fatal error: myproject/someheader.h: No such file or directory
```

How can I include the /usr/local/include directory when building the project? Normally, I'd add

```
INC=-I/usr/local/include
```

But that's not working, I guess I need to add the header files some other way?

Comment: `INC` is not mentioned in the makefile you've posted. Perhaps it's
mentioned in the `/usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk` that you haven't posted? It's certainly unncessary to create symlinks to tell the compiler
where it should look for headers but you'd need to post the
makefile where the compiler flags are actually set and used to
get a non-guess answer.

Comment: Here's the Makefile: https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile/blob/master/Arduino.mk. I totally agree that it's necessary. But it seems the Arduino makefile doesn't care about the regular include directories.

Comment: Here is [the README file](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile/blob/master/README.md)
of Arduino-Makefile. Read there about **Including Libraries** and `ARDUINO_SKETCHBOOK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up adding a symbolic link from the arduino directory to the location of my library:

```
ln -s /usr/local/include /usr/share/arduino/libraries/Custom
```

Then, I added the "Custom" "library" to the arduino makefile, my makefile is now:

```
OBJDIR          = ../build

ARDUINO_DIR = /usr/share/arduino

TARGET      = main

MCU     = atmega328p

F_CPU       = 16000000

ARDUINO_PORT    = /dev/ttyACM0
AVRDUDE_ARD_PROGRAMMER  = arduino
AVRDUDE_ARD_BAUDRATE    = 115200
ARDUINO_LIBS    = Custom # <---- !

include /usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk
```

The build process seems to obtain my header files now